# How to filter trait objects in a hashmap to a vector and pass to a function?

Tags: rust

I'm having some trouble using trait objects in data structures and passing them around to functions correctly.

Suppose I have a custom trait `MyTrait`, and a struct defined as

```rust
struct MyStruct<'a> {
    my_stuff: HashMap<String, Box<dyn MyTrait + 'a>>
}
```

Additionally, I have a function that needs to take in a vector of things that satisfy `MyTrait` and operate on them in a read-only manner. I have it currently defined as

```rust
fn do_something(things: Vec<&Box<dyn MyTrait>>) {

    // We'll do something here that only READS data off each thing, no modification

}
```

Now suppose I'm given a vector of strings `ids: Vec<String>`, and I want to acquire the corresponding vector of trait objects from the `my_stuff` map so that I can pass it to my `do_something` function. I tried something like this:

```rust
let my_vec: Vec<&Box<dyn MyTrait>> = my_stuff
    .iter()
    .filter(|(id, _m)| ids.contains(id))
    .map(|(_id, m)| m)
    .collect();
```

In my real problem, things compile for me up to this point. However, once I try to do `do_something(my_vec);` it reprimands me:

```
.map(|(_id, m)| m)
                ^ returning this value requires that `'a` must outlive `'static`
```

I've searched around and tried so many things and am at a bit of an impasse now, because I feel strongly my problem will benefit from using trait objects, and that this scheme of passing a vector of things implementing `MyTrait` to a function to have it read off data and compute something is needed, but I can't for the life of me get it working. I welcome any and all suggestions that might remedy this for this Rust newb.

Comment: Have you tried giving the trait objects the lifetime `'a` in the type of `my_vec` too, ie. `let my_vec: Vec<&Box<dyn MyTrait + 'a>> = ...;`?

Comment: I get the same error if I add the lifetime as you suggest. I should maybe note that the creation of `my_vec` is happening inside a function implemented for `MyStruct`, so I'm actually doing the filter/map steps on `self.my_stuff`.

Comment: It works if you annotate the lifetime in `do_something()`, `things: Vec<&Box<dyn MyTrait + '_>>`

Comment: Note that if you control `do_something`, it's better to take a `Vec<&dyn MyTrait + '_>` in order to avoid the double indirection, or possibly even an `impl IntoIterator<Item = &dyn MyTrait + '_>` to avoid the cost of `collect`ing if `do_something` simply iterates through the objects.

Comment: Ah, you're correct @ChayimFriedman, once I put that type annotation in my function definition it compiled. If you write up an answer I can mark accepted.

Comment: @Jmb thank you for the suggestion, that sounds like a good step and I'll try to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `do_something()` only accepts `dyn MyTrait + 'static`, so the lifetime does not live long enough. Change its signature to `fn do_something(things: Vec<&Box<dyn MyTrait + '_>>)` and it'll work.

Even better, take `Vec<&dyn MyTrait>`. Then you save an indirection, and also don't need to specify the lifetime explicitly - it's implied. You can also change `do_something()` to take `impl Iterator` or `impl IntoIterator`, assuming it doesn't need a `Vec` specifically, then you don't need to `collect()`.

Comment: You are a life saver my friend. I ended up going with the latter suggestion using the reference and removing the lifetime annotations altogether. Thank you!